# how to access a set of data from bootstrap modal by passing a single id to it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

here i want to pass data-id to the modal and i want to access all other student data to be accessed from the modal when clicking on the edit button. how to access these data in bootstrap modal by passing a single value 'data-id' to it? i can use the jquery too.

my code is

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Father Name</th>
            <th>Mother Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <? $count=1; ?>
    <?php foreach($students as $student): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['roll']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $student['photo']; ?>"     width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['sex']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['father_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['mother_name']; ?></td>
            <td><button data-id="<? echo $student['name']; ?>" class="btn btn-success edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_modal">Edit</button>&nbsp;
            <button data-id="<? echo $student['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_modal">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <? $count++; ?>

    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit different way of loading modals.

Right now you're triggering it on click (automatically), but if you want to pass the ID to the modal then you would like to trigger modal programatically.

PHP:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Roll No</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Father Name</th>
            <th>Mother Name</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <? $count=1; ?>
    <?php foreach($students as $student): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['roll']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $student['photo']; ?>"     width="100px" height="100px"/></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['sex']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['address']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['father_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $student['mother_name']; ?></td>
            <td><button data-id="<? echo $student['name']; ?>" class="btn btn-success btn_modal edit" data-target-modal="#edit_modal">Edit</button>&nbsp;
            <button data-id="<? echo $student['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn_modal" data-target-modal="#delete_modal">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <? $count++; ?>

    </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Now it depends how you want to pass the data-id to the modal. If you're using an iframe i suggest pass it in the URL params like url.com/data-id or if you're fetching somethings via ajax then just include the ajax in the below click trigger code, it will work fine.

JS:

```
$('.btn_modal').on('click', function(e)
{

var dataId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
var modalId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-target-modal');

 // Ajax Function to load up the details or html for modal to render -- pass the dataId as params
$.ajax({
url: 'someurl.php?student_id='+dataId,
type: "GET",
success: function(data)
{
    // Here either you replace the html of the called modal or just replace values depends on what you've thought of.
},
error: function(e)
{
  console.log(e);
}
  });

$('#'+modalId).modal('show');

});
```

Comment: i wanted to access the data from the database from the modal by passing the student id to the modal

Comment: @RafeequeKP How're you planning on getting the Data from db into the modal (suppose you've the student id now)? by ajax or by php?

Comment: @RafeequeKP so I assume you call some page & pass student id to that to load up the appropriate details & then show it in the modal? Is the modal having an iframe?

Comment: i am passing the id from a page and the modal is also in the same page..not passing id to different page

Comment: @RafeequeKP see my updated code above. you will have to make changes as per your requirements in that code.

Answer (score 0):

You want your php variables in modal to display data related to the id clicked. For this you want your modal to fetch data dynamically. So set a $_SESSION['modal']['student'] variable and set it to null on page load.

In modal, check if $_SESSION['modal']['student'] is null or not, if not null, fill the modal with data to display.

Now to get data in this variable, use ajax, so when clicked on user, fetch ID using jQuery, make an ajax call and on the set your $_SESSION['modal']['student'] variable with required data running your db queries. On success function of AJAX, toggle modal on, which will now display your set data. And in modal php isset clause, in the end after displaying, unset your $_SESSION['modal']['student'] variable.

Alternately, use JSON to return data to your success function in AJAX and set your displayable innerHTML's using jQuery/JS and this response data. Now toggle your modal to show.

Keep in mind to check if variables are set before displaying, to avoid errors on first time page load.